# How to use lsp-pyright in emacs?

Tags: emacs, python-language-server

I want python language server support with auto completion and syntax highlighting. I cloned the lsp-pyright repo from their [github-page](https://github.com/emacs-lsp/lsp-pyright).
After that, I wanted to load the path and use it. But somehow I get an error (run with --debug-init):

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (file-missing "Cannot open load file" "No such file or directory" "lsp-mode")
  require(lsp-mode)
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*-106525> nil "/home/johannes/.emacs.d/lsp-pyright/lsp-pyright.el" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 1077
  load-with-code-conversion("/home/johannes/.emacs.d/lsp-pyright/lsp-pyright.el" "/home/johannes/.emacs.d/lsp-pyright/lsp-pyright.el" nil t)
  require(lsp-pyright)
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*> nil "/home/johannes/.emacs.d/init.el" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 901
  load-with-code-conversion("/home/johannes/.emacs.d/init.el" "/home/johannes/.emacs.d/init.el" t t)
  load("/home/johannes/.emacs.d/init" noerror nomessage)
  startup--load-user-init-file(#f(compiled-function () #<bytecode 0x9e00fc3fd2117b8>) #f(compiled-function () #<bytecode -0x1f3c686ddc0cdc35>) t)
  command-line()
  normal-top-level()
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (file-missing "Cannot open load file" "No such file or directory" "lsp-mode")
```

I am confused, because doing that for emacs-evil worked fine for me. Why not set up an lsp-server like that (I don't even know if this is a sensible try..)?

I could also use eglot. In fact, I used eglot with clangd for C++ development already and it works like a charm.

This is my entire init.el file:

```
(setq inhibit-startup-screen t)

(menu-bar-mode 0)
(tool-bar-mode 0)
(scroll-bar-mode 0) 


(custom-set-variables
 '(custom-safe-themes
   '("d80952c58cf1b06d936b1392c38230b74ae1a2a6729594770762dc0779ac66b7" default))
 '(package-selected-packages '(el-search treeview gruvbox-theme eglot)))
(custom-set-faces)

;;evil
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/evil/")
(require 'evil)
(evil-mode 1)

;;tabstop
(setq-default tab-width 4)

;;clangd
(require 'eglot)
(add-to-list 'eglot-server-programs '((c++-mode c-mode) "clangd"))
(add-hook 'c-mode-hook 'eglot-ensure)
(add-hook 'c++-mode-hook 'eglot-ensure)

;;emacs theme
(load-theme 'gruvbox-dark-hard t)

;;  (add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/vendor/pymacs-0.24-beta2")
;; (require 'pymacs)
;; (pymacs-load "ropemacs" "rope-")
;; (setq ropemacs-enable-autoimport t)

;; pyright
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/lsp-pyright/")
(require 'lsp-pyright)
```

I tried reading through [this](https://joaotavora.github.io/eglot/#Eglot-and-LSP-Servers) to understand how to use eglot in the first place, but that didn't help either.

Putting this in my config didn't help:
`(use-package lsp-pyright :ensure t :hook (python-mode . (lambda () (require 'lsp-pyright) (lsp))))  ; or lsp-deferred`

I coudln't find any website that illustrates this process in an easy and understandable way.
[Pyright-Installation(emacs)](https://microsoft.github.io/pyright/#/installation)

It does not have to be pyright btw. Just a tool that works! (like ropemacs).
[ropemacs](https://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2010/05/my-emacs-python-environment/)
This was an interesting read, but after following this step by step, I noticed, that some of these github url's are depecated and no longer usable. (so this didn't work either :( ..)

I know this might be a noob-question, but I just didn't get it to work.
How would I go about resolving this? Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: "But somehow I get an error. " You should at least paste the error.

Comment: The error indicates that you don't have `lsp-mode` installed in your `load-path`. This type of basic computer error is probably not a good fit for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @tripleee Why not? How to install it and add it to the load path?

Comment: Probably best to use `package-mode` if you are not familiar with how to install libraries yourself. Perhaps try https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/71826/unable-to-setup-lsp-mode-with-lsp-pyright

Comment: @tripleee Doom-emacs support lsp out of the box. Would you recommend this?

Comment: I have no experience with Doom Emacs. My impression is that it's beginner friendly, but some of those "features" I would probably turn off. The preference for `vi` keybindings in particular seems dubious. But I see you are an `evil` victim already anyway.

Comment: please install lsp-mode referring lsp-mode doc: https://emacs-lsp.github.io/lsp-mode/page/installation/